# Grouping sequences of rows - BigQuery / SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to group a sequence of rows that have the same value in one determinate field. For instance, I have a series of Selina Kyle's records between two Bruce Wayne's records. I need to group those records by username, but as long as they are in a immediate sequence. For instance, I have this table:

`|User        | Time |Date_In                |Date_Out            |
|Bruce Wayne | 2793 |2017-08-30 09:55:52    |2017-08-30 10:42:25 |
|Selina Kyle | 2430 |2017-08-30 10:42:25    |2017-08-30 11:22:55 |
|Selina Kyle | 4461 |2017-08-30 11:22:55    |2017-08-30 12:37:16 |
|Selina Kyle | 4356 |2017-08-30 12:37:16    |2017-08-30 13:49:52 |
|Selina Kyle | 2295 |2017-08-30 13:49:52    |2017-08-30 14:28:07 |
|Bruce Wayne | 2098 |2017-08-30 14:28:07    |2017-08-30 15:03:05 |`

I need to group it by username and sum time, but I need the Bruce Wayne records separetely, because they are not in a immediate sequence:

`|User          |Time    |Date_In               |Date_Out           |
|Bruce Wayne   |2793    |2017-08-30 09:55:52   |2017-08-30 10:42:25|
|Selina Kyle   |13542   |2017-08-30 10:42:25   |2017-08-30 14:28:07|
|Bruce Wayne   |2098    |2017-08-30 14:28:07   |2017-08-30 15:03:05|`

Comment: How do you know what the sequence is? Do you have some other column with a timestamp or sequence number?

Comment: Yes! I have date in and a date out column, but the issue is how I can group them by sequences of usernames that are the same. For this specific issue, you can assume that the first table is already ordered, so I already have the right sequence.

Comment: tables in BigQuery DO NOT have any physical or logical ordering by itself . - so you MUST have some column that will define an order. As soon as you add it to your question - it is matter of few minutes to put answer on your question ! and btw, please DO post the schema/example in your question, do not use links/images.

Comment: I have just adjusted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT MIN(User) AS User, SUM(TIME) AS TIME, MIN(Date_In) AS Date_In, MAX(Date_Out) AS Date_Out
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    COUNTIF(User != IFNULL(prev_User, User)) OVER(ORDER BY Date_In) AS groupid
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 
      LAG(User) OVER(ORDER BY Date_In) AS prev_User
    FROM `yourTable`
    ORDER BY Date_In
  )
)
GROUP BY groupid
-- ORDER BY Date_In
```

You can play/test this with dummy data from your question as in below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `yourTable` AS (
  SELECT 'Bruce Wayne'AS User, 2793 AS TIME, '2017-08-30 09:55:52' AS Date_In, '2017-08-30 10:42:25' AS Date_Out UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Selina Kyle', 2430, '2017-08-30 10:42:25', '2017-08-30 11:22:55' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Selina Kyle', 4461, '2017-08-30 11:22:55', '2017-08-30 12:37:16' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Selina Kyle', 4356, '2017-08-30 12:37:16', '2017-08-30 13:49:52' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Selina Kyle', 2295, '2017-08-30 13:49:52', '2017-08-30 14:28:07' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bruce Wayne', 2098, '2017-08-30 14:28:07', '2017-08-30 15:03:05' 
)
SELECT MIN(User) AS User, SUM(TIME) AS TIME, MIN(Date_In) AS Date_In, MAX(Date_Out) AS Date_Out
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    COUNTIF(User != IFNULL(prev_User, User)) OVER(ORDER BY Date_In) AS groupid
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 
      LAG(User) OVER(ORDER BY Date_In) AS prev_User
    FROM `yourTable`
    ORDER BY Date_In
  )
)
GROUP BY groupid
ORDER BY Date_In
```

Please note - from your example it looks like you have case when there are no overlapping of date_out and date_in in consecutive rows - if you do have - above query needs to be further adjusted to reflect logic of how to treat such case